# error when building , getting : "suspect or "

Tags: go, debugging

I'm encountering a build issue with go. I'm wondering if it's a bug in the compiler or a problem with the code.

```
// removed the error handling for sake of clarity 

file, _ := c.FormFile("file")
openedFile, _ := file.Open()
buffer := make([]byte, 512)
n, _ := openedFile.Read(buffer)

contentType := http.DetectContentType(buffer[:n])

// doesn't work

if contentType != "image/jpeg"  || contentType != "image/png" {
  return 
}

// works 

if contentType != "image/jpeg" {
    return
}
else if contentType != "image/png" {
    return
}
```

error `suspect or: contentType != "image/jpeg" || contentType != "image/png"`

fyi " c.FormFile("file") " is form Gin gonic. but it shouldnt really matter.

Comment: Except it is a suspect or: your if statement will always be true as `contentType` can't be equal to both `image/jpeg` and `image/png` at the same time.

Comment: Chances to detect an actual compiler bug with Joe Average type code are nil.

Comment: when googling only 2 post came up both being issues referencing errors from the compiler on or

Comment: Note that `if ... { ... return } else` is always redundant.  Delete `else`.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

What you see is a compiler warning, but the app will run.

Your condition is always `true`:

```
contentType != "image/jpeg"  || contentType != "image/png"
```

You compare a `string` variable to 2 different `string` values (using not equal), so one of them will surely be `true`, and `true || false` is always `true`.

Most likely you need logical AND: I assume you want to test if the content type is neither JPEG nor PNG:

```
if contentType != "image/jpeg" && contentType != "image/png" {
    return 
}
```